# Unity3d instantaneous speed up of player movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in unity3d I have a player that moves constantly forward with a certain speed and I control only it's left or right position.
I want my player to speed up instantaneously when it encounters an object and a trigger is enabled.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Any ideas?

```
void Update () 
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 4, 0, horizVel);    
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 4, 0, horizVel * 10.0f);
    }
}
```

horizVel is a public variable for my velocity set to 10.

Comment: I think it might be that your second getcomponent rigid body calls the rigid body of the colliding object, not the player object. Try setting a variable in your script that keeps your player rigid body and use that perhaps.

Comment: @Robin Sounds logic, I'll try it

Comment: @Robin it calls it on the object this script is attached to, if it were to call it on the colliding object they would have to use `other.gameObject.getComponent<>`

Comment: @Eddge thanks, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be because you have hardcoded your speed variable `OnTriggerEnter` methods, instead of updating it.

Update is called once a frame. If your `horizVel` is set to 10, it will move at a speed of 10 once per frame.

When you hit `OnTriggerEnter` your `horizVel` gets updated to 10x that of what it was before, i.e: 100.

**BUT**, because you've not *updated* your speed variable, when you come back round to the `Update` method, your `horizVel` will be back at 10 again.

I think what you should be trying is this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
    {
         horizVel *= 10f;
    }
}
```

That way your speed variable will stay at 10x that of what it was before INSTEAD of for just the collision period.

**EDIT**
*"I tried this but the speed remains boosted not only in the collision period"*

Then you can use a coroutine to reset the speed variable back to its original value:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
    {
         horizVel *= 10f;
         StartCoroutine(ResetSpeedAfterTime(5f));
    }
}

// Resets the speed variable back to the original value after a set amount of time
private IEnumerator ResetSpeedAfterTime(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    horizVel = 10f; // the original speed value;
}
```

Comment: @AsukaMatseli in which case you could use a `Coroutine` to reset the speed variable back to the original speed after a certain amount of time.

Comment: @AsukaMatseli I have updated my answer to give an example.

Comment: Great stuff! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a beginner at C# and my answer may not be correct but have you tried assigning an id to the game object that is supposed to make the character speed up and then calling it in the statement

> if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")

It maybe because the engine is unable to calculate the exact moment the collision is taking place

Comment: I've used print() to check if it is getting in the if and i noticed that it enters. It doesn't speed up though ...

Comment: Try using Speed Boost instead of SpeedUp. Maintain the  single space in between Speed and Boost.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the speed to be boosted when your object is in within the trigger bounds you can reverse the speed after your character leaves the collider.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
    {
         horizVel *= 10f;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
    {
         horizVel /= 10f;
    }
}
```